# Role of "with" in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

In a film ([Horrible Bosses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horrible_Bosses)) a person said:
*"I'm this close to getting a big promotion **with** my own office."*

Why he used **"with"**?

Answer (score 2):

A private office is one of the perks *accompanying* the promotion.

Comment: Might add that in this case the _office_ is room he would be working in, rather than the general workplace.  OP's confusion is that he thinks it should be _"at my office"_ - i.e. a promotion at work.